# Xcode 'GoogleUtilities/GULNSDATA+zlib.h' file not found, after adding FirebaseRemoteConfig to Podfile

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

None of the (vaguely) similar questions have answers which help here. I added `pod 'GoogleUtilities'` to the Podfile and that did not help. What is wrong here?

Comment: There's like an issue that can be seen in the Podfile.lock. Please share both that and the Podfile if you're still stuck